# Cannot get valid Credentials for Youtube v3 API

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am going through [this getting-started tutorial](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) for Youtube v3 API interaction.

I've created new sandbox project and used (copy/paste) the provided code there.  Went on our GCE project, created credentials and pasted it into my sandbox project.

I keep getting the response from youtube service, saying that Credentials are Invalid.

```
...
File ".../python-sandbox/googleapiclient/http.py", line 842, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?alt=json&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&forUsername=GoogleDevelopers returned "Invalid Credentials">
```

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Is this because the Credentials are created from different project than used on?

Comment: `"Invalid Credentials"` is not this sufficient?

Comment: @ElisByberi that's the problem. I don't know why they are Invalid. I tried re-creating them and still the same.

Comment: How are you creating them?

Comment: The same steps as described in tutorial. Google console (Selecting Project) -> Credentials -> New Credentials (OAuth client ID) -> Web Application -> set name and Authorized redirect URIs (localhost:8090/oauth2callback).

Comment: something is wrong with the client id or secret you copied.

Comment: @DaImTo I've created new Credentials, actually several times, and still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube service was not allowed on business account